# Combining LongPress with Swipe UIGesture in Swift 5 (Xcode 10.1)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

I've seen other people ask similar questions but I didn't really understand the answers. I'm new to iOS design and relatively new to Swift, so I apologize for my ignorance. My goal is to have the user swipe in a given direction and have the program repeat a certain action until the user lifts his finger from the screen. From what I can tell, I need to implement the gestureRecognizer function.

I think I probably implemented things in a weird way:

In my GameViewController.swift file, I implemented the following, as a separate function under the UIViewController class.

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)-> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Which I understand to mean that any two UIGestureRecognizer actions can occur at the same time.

In my GameScene.swift file, under the SKScene class, I have:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    ...

    swipeRight =  UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeR))
    swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeL))
    longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(printLongPress))

    longPress.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
    swipeRight.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
    swipeLeft.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

    swipeRight.direction = .right
    swipeLeft.direction = .left

    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
}


@objc func swipeR() {
    print("Right")
}
@objc func swipeL() {
    print("Left")
}
@objc func printLongPress() {
    print("Long press")
}
```

Ideally in the example code described here, if you were to swipe right and hold onto the screen, you'd see "Swipe Right" "Long Press" "Long Press" etc.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: UIGestureRecognizers are meant to simplify things that other UIViewController overrides (touchesBegan, touchesMoved,  touchesEnded) do. I really don't think you want to use a combination of long press and swipe - even *if* you can get these types of gesture recognizers to work, consider the user. I would never think of needing to combine these two. I think you have two alternatives. First, look into UIPanGestureRecognizer. You can find it's location and determine if it's a start, end, of something in between. Maybe this would do what you need. Second, look into those overrides I mentioned.

Comment: Here's two links that may help you with UIPanGesture: First, this is written in Swift 3, but I'm not seeing too much that would be different - https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2017/02/uipangesturerecognizer-tutorial-in.html Second, here' a more up to date (and generic) tutorial for UIGestureRecognizer: https://www.raywenderlich.com/433-uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll give this a shot